# Disable nginx logs for specific location (path)

Tags: nginx, logging

I need to exclude records from nginx`s`access.log` for specific url (location).

I have found a solution like this:

```
location /status/alive {
    access_log off;
}
```

but... I can`t access via web too for this location (www.some-site.com/status/alive). I am getting 404 nginx response (but should get 200)

So, the question is:

- how I can have access to .../status/alive with 200 response (my web app return this response)
- how I can exclude only this location logs from access.log?

Comment: Is that the only line you have in the location bracket? No proxy_pass, redirect, or anything that "brings" the connection to the expected destination? (like return 200 or proxy_pass to your app for it to return 200).

Comment: yes, for `location /status/alive` there is only one option - access_log off

Comment: Then if you have another bracket for location / {} that proxy pass, the connection won't enter there. Can you add where are you proxy_passing? Or the general nginx configuration changing domains and uri for anonymous ones.